# double sqrt (surd) symbol

Tags: math-mode, spacing, macros, symbols

I want to define a macro that prints two adjacent sqrt symbols.
(Notation from Cauchy's analysis book).

[image]

I get something close but the spacing is changing depending if there is a number before it. If there is not a number in front the sqrt (surd) symbols are too close.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[class=book]{book}
% Run with xelatex

%%% fonts
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%% mathfonts
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\usepackage{microtype}


% "221A is the surd symbol in unicode. \surd is not working, it shows a p
\usepackage{mathtools}
\NewDocumentCommand\dsqrt{o m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \,\mathrlap{\char"221A}\,\char"221A#2%
  }%
  {
    \,\mathrlap{\raisebox{3pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}\mathrlap{\char"221A}\,\char"221A#2%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{pre1}
\dsqrt{a} = \pm\sqrt{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{pre1}
2\dsqrt{a} = \pm2\sqrt{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{pre1}
\dsqrt[n]{a} = \pm\sqrt[n]{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{pre1}
2\dsqrt[n]{a} = \pm2\sqrt[n]{a}
\end{equation}

And here is another: inline  $\dsqrt{y} =\pm \sqrt{y}$.

And here is another: inline  $2\dsqrt{y} =\pm 2\sqrt{y}$.

And here is another: inline $\dsqrt[n]{y} =\pm \sqrt[n]{y}$.

And here is another: inline $2\dsqrt[n]{y} =\pm 2\sqrt[n]{y}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Obviously I'm no Cauchy but his notation is ugly as hell.

Comment: At the moment in the old book looks nicer, but I don't like either. I am working in a translation

Comment: @TeXtnik Can you post an image of the original?

Comment: You can see an example here (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/196902/Cauchy.pdf)

Comment: @TeXtnik -- can you please provide the full bibliographic information on the book?  (i've forwarded information regarding this inquiry to my unicode contacts.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: You can find a fascimile [here](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k29058v/f1.image.r=); with the following bibliographyc informaation (and more) Titre :  Analyse algébrique ([Reprod. en fac-sim.]) / Augustin-Louis Cauchy 
Auteur :  Cauchy, Augustin-Louis (1789-1857) 
Éditeur :  J. Gabay (Sceaux) 
Date d'édition :  1821

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another attempt; unfortunately, it seems that the “surd” symbol is not available in Unicode.

```
\documentclass{book}
% Run with xelatex

%%% fonts
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%% mathfonts
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\usepackage{microtype}

% "221A is the surd symbol in unicode. \surd is not working, it shows a p
\NewDocumentCommand\dsqrt{o m}{%
  \mathop{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
      {\doublesurd}
      {\mathrlap{^{\scriptscriptstyle#1}}\doublesurd}%
  }%
  {}#2
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doublesurd}{\mathpalette\double@surd\relax}
\newcommand{\double@surd}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\char"221A$\hidewidth\cr$\m@th#1\,\char"221A$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\dsqrt{a} = \pm\sqrt{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
2\dsqrt{a} = \pm2\sqrt{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\dsqrt[n]{a} = \pm\sqrt[n]{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
2\dsqrt[n]{a} = \pm2\sqrt[n]{a}
\end{equation}

And here is another: inline  $\dsqrt{y} =\pm \sqrt{y}$.

And here is another: inline  $2\dsqrt{y} =\pm 2\sqrt{y}$.

And here is another: inline $\dsqrt[n]{y} =\pm \sqrt[n]{y}$.

And here is another: inline $2\dsqrt[n]{y} =\pm 2\sqrt[n]{y}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I choose this one, because I think it gives better result at different math style.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version that uses stacks.  It is not currently set up to obey the smaller math styles, however.

```
\documentclass[class=book]{book}
% Run with xelatex

%%% fonts
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
%%% mathfonts
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\usepackage{microtype}


% "221A is the surd symbol in unicode. \surd is not working, it shows a p
\usepackage{mathtools}
\NewDocumentCommand\dsqrt{o m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \,\stackengine{0pt}{\char"221A}{\,\char"221A#2}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}%
  }%
  {
    \,\raisebox{3pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}\mkern-13mu\stackengine{0pt}{\char"221A}{\,\char"221A#2}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{pre1}
\dsqrt{a} = \pm\sqrt{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{pre1}
2\dsqrt{a} = \pm2\sqrt{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{pre1}
\dsqrt[n]{a} = \pm\sqrt[n]{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{pre1}
2\dsqrt[n]{a} = \pm2\sqrt[n]{a}
\end{equation}

And here is another: inline  $\dsqrt{y} =\pm \sqrt{y}$.

And here is another: inline  $2\dsqrt{y} =\pm 2\sqrt{y}$.

And here is another: inline $\dsqrt[n]{y} =\pm \sqrt[n]{y}$.

And here is another: inline $2\dsqrt[n]{y} =\pm 2\sqrt[n]{y}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

If one wanted the surd to match the argument size (as occurs with the `\sqrt`), then this definition should be substituted:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\dsqrt{o m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \,\stackengine{0pt}{\sqrt{\vphantom{#2}}}{\,\sqrt{#2}}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}%
  }%
  {
    \,\raisebox{3pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}\mkern-13mu\stackengine{0pt}{%
      \sqrt{\vphantom{#2}}}{\,\sqrt{#2}}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}%
  }
}
```

Notice the difference with an `x` vs. a `y` argument.

[image]