# Bold square root with normal argument

Tags: bold, sqrt

This is a somewhat funny question. To explain the problem of complex extensions of the principal square root, I would like to have two visibly different square root signs within the same document; for example, besides the usual one, a boldface square root sign, yet hosting a normally typed argument. I have no clues.  If not possible, I would be grateful for suggestions about totally different solutions...

Comment: See the \surd character and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287412/double-sqrt-surd-symbol?s=1|2.2694 (for example).

Comment: Thanks. There was this funny idea of the double sign, which I will use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course this can be done with the `bm` package. The usage is detailed in the [package documentation](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/bm.pdf) section 3.3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$\bm\sqrtsign{x} \quad \text{vs.} \quad \sqrt{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would urge you to come up with something a little bit more noticeable.

Comment: strange as it may seem, I can be wrong (especially this time of night:-) I think I'll delete my answer in that case